# I keep getting ''missing number treated as zero'' and ''illegal unit of measure (pt. inserted)'' error :(

Tags: errors, wrapfigure

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}
\centering  
\includegraphics{DoorNumbers.png}
\caption{Door assignment}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong? i get it at the `\centering` line. thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you checked `texdoc wrapfigure`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `wrapfigure` environment has *two* mandatory arguments; you are missing the one used for the width:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{DoorNumbers.png} 
\caption{Door assignment}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Instead of `\linewidth`, use the length that better suits your needs.

Comment: Never mind, i already found it, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Pim Ah, OK! Don't forget that you can [`accept the answer`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954) if you consider it solved your problem.